# What carries electric field through space?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, photons, charge, carrier-particles

A stationary charge "creates" a constant (but not uniform) electric field around it, and a moving charge "creates" a variable electric field around it. What "carries" the information about the existence of a stationary or a moving charge through space?

In particular, are photons necessarily involved in the process?

Comment: The electromagnetic field. Charges are the sources and the fields are the response. In turn charges respond to the fields... and that's where calculating things turns into hard work. You are probably looking for a less trivial response, though?

Comment: @CuriousOne do you simply mean "a force from a distance"?

Comment: Electrodynamics is a completely local theory.

Comment: @CuriousOne I'm not limiting the question to electrodynamics

Comment: In that case you still end up with local theories describing local effect.

Comment: @CuriousOne Wikipedia: `The concept of locality is that, for an action at one point to have an influence at another point, something in the space between the points, such as a field, must mediate the action. To exert an influence, something, such as a wave or particle, must travel through the space between the two points, to carry the influence.`  - what exactly is this "mediation" and what is the "something"?

Comment: @Sparkler The classical field exists at all points in between and it evolves in a completely local way, with the change in the value of the field at a location completely determined by the spatial variation of the field values at that point (and the current at that point). Exactly as spelled out in my answer to v1 of your OP.

Comment: That something is called the electromagnetic field. I thought that was obvious? What are you looking for? The aether? We've exorcized that a while ago.

Comment: @CuriousOne by EM field you mean photons?

Comment: No, I mean the electromagnetic field.

Comment: @CuriousOne no underlying particles whatsoever?

Comment: Particles are an emergent phenomenon. Well, it's really just particle tracks... but people like to mistake one for the other.

Comment: @CuriousOne If no particles, where's the field energy coming from?

Comment: I have no idea why a particle (which is a choice by a physicist to ignore the actual size of a physical object) would be needed for the ability to perform work. Your questions aren't making any logical sense to me.

Comment: @CuriousOne http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/70054/why-do-electrons-emit-radiation implies that electric field is photons, no?

Comment: Am I supposed to find something special in that question?

Comment: [Read](https://independent.academia.edu/HolgerFiedler) about "Are photons composed particles" and more in detail about "Complex one-dimensional structures of space".

Answer (score 3):

Macroscopically we speak of electric and magnetic fields which follow the classical theory of Maxwell's equations.

> A stationary charge "creates" a constant (but not uniform) electric field around it, and a moving charge "creates" a variable electric field around it. What "carries" the information about the existence of a stationary or a moving charge through space?

In the classical theory there is no necessity for "carrying" stationary electric and magnetic fields, the equations attribute fields to charges and magnetic moments which need no "carrying". The fields describe the behavior of charges and dipoles . For variable fields, classical theory's mathematics accepts that they propagate as electromagnetic waves in vacuum with velocity c, with no need of a medium. The theory fits the data perfectly.

> In particular, are photons necessarily involved in the process?

Classical electromagnetism is an emergent theory from the underlying [quantum electrodynamics.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_electrodynamics). There the photon is an elementary particle of zero mass and spin 1, traveling with velocity c  and is the carrier of electromagnetic interactions, either in [virtual form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_particle) or real. An enormous number of photons build up the classcial electromagnetic wave, as demonstrated [here](http://motls.blogspot.com/2011/11/how-classical-fields-particles-emerge.html).

So yes, photons are necessarily involved as the carrier of the EM interactions.

Comment: Is that the reason that all objects emit in the IR? (Vibrational energy of the atoms creates alternating electromagnetic field) if yes, how is this consistent with non radiative relaxation (internal conversion, vibrational relaxation)?

Comment: @Sparkler Yes, black body radiation is photon emission from spill over fields in bulk matter. Internal conversions etc would belong to virtual photon exchanges.

Answer (score 2):

This question illustrates a crucial difference between fundamental fields and everyday ones.

Everyday fields are made by averaging over many particles. For example, consider a sound wave in air. It's nothing more than a ripple in the 'displacement field': it says that at one point, the air is stretched, while at some other point, it gets be squeezed.

But if you zoom all the way in, to the level of individual air molecules, you'll find that nothing is getting stretched or squished at all! In fact, if you look at a single air molecule at some moment, you won't have any idea whether it's in a sound wave or not. We only see sound waves when we average over the positions over many air molecules; the individual molecules make up the field.

Fundamental fields, like the electromagnetic field, are *not* the same way. Such fields are not made of anything; we do not construct them out of smaller pieces! In particular, **the electromagnetic field is not "made of" photons** like air is made of air molecules. This misconception suggests that if you got rid of all the photons in a region, the electromagnetic field would cease to exist there, which is totally false.

A better analogy is that photons are like sound waves. You can quiet a room, but the air will still be there; similarly, the electromagnetic field as an entity still exists when there are no photons.

So, to answer your question: the electromagnetic field carries electromagnetic waves. The waves are made of photons; they are not being carried by photons.

Comment: So the electric and the magnetic field are made from nothing? Not to think about this does not mean that it is so. The question shows our not-knowledge about this phenomenon.

Comment: Under standard physics. Since the OP asked about photons I assume that's what they wanted to know.

Answer (score 1):

I would say photons as they are mediators of electromagnetic interaction. But I wouldn't say something is actually carrying information about the moving or stationary charge, it's just the field itself, as it is changing at the origin and is propogating at c. So the change of field at a certain point away from source is not immediate, there is a delay. And only after that time you find out that the charge is moving.

Comment: are photons necessarily involved in the process?

Comment: If the answer is expressed in term of quantum field theory, then yes, photons are involved: virtual photons. Read Richard Feynman's "QED: The strange thory of light and matter"; videos of the original lectures are available online.

Answer (score 0):

Currents and magnetic fields are what creates changes in electric fields. Without them, electric fields stay the same.

And it is electric fields that make magnetic fields change, without them, magnetic fields stay the same.

In particular here are the explicit equations for the electromagnetic field and $$\frac{\partial \vec E}{\partial t}=\frac{1}{\epsilon_0}\left(-\vec J+\frac{1}{\mu_0}\vec \nabla\times \vec B\right)$$ tells the electric part of the field how to change and 
$$\frac{\partial \vec B}{\partial t}=-\vec \nabla\times \vec E$$ tells the magnetic part of the field how to change.

So if you had a charge that had always been at rest at the origin the magnetic field might initially be $\vec 0$ and the electric field might initially be $\frac{q\hat r}{4\pi \epsilon_0|\vec r|^2}$ and then if you moved the charge it would have a current which would make the electric field change and the new electric field could make the magnetic field change. The new magnetic field could make the electric field change and so on, like a ripple effect that expands at the speed of light. Each field changing in time based on the spatial variation of the field values around it.

Comment: are photons involved in the process?

Comment: @Timaeus, you are only citing 2 out of the 4 Maxwell equations. All 4 are needed to describe the EM field ! https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell%27s_equations

Comment: @Anael I cited the evolution equations, the constraint equations are impositions on the initial conditions, they don't tell you how things change in time. And the question wasn't about which kinds of initial conditions are allowed, it was about how things are created. The new fields are created out of the old fields according to the evolution equations.

Comment: @Timaeus, My bad, it wasn't clear on my first read!

Comment: @Sparkler, Combining Maxwell's equations result in a Wave equation that describes the propagation of the EM field. Photons in particular are a discretization of the energy carried by those waves.

Comment: @Anael so photons are always involved? in other words, is the photon the carrier of electric field?

Comment: @Anael No, a classical electromagnetic field corresponds only to a particular kind of multiphoton state. But the OP should ask new questions when the OP has new questions. This is **not** a site where you have one question per person and you edit your one question each time you have a new idea, thus invalidating existing answers to your original question.